# How can I achieve optimistic rendering with remote data using material-table?

Tags: material-table

I am using the library [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) for data tables in my application.  I was setting the data prop to use data from this.state.data and adding rows would update on my table by using setState.  But after switching to remote data the table doesn't update after adding a row.  Is there another way to achieve this with remote data?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import Add from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
import Edit from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import FirstPage from "@material-ui/icons/FirstPage";
import ChevronRight from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import LastPage from "@material-ui/icons/LastPage";
import ChevronLeft from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft";
import Search from "@material-ui/icons/Search";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={[
        {
          title: "Avatar",
          field: "avatar",
          render: rowData => (
            <img
              style={{ height: 36, borderRadius: "50%" }}
              src={rowData.avatar}
            />
          )
        },
        { title: "Id", field: "id" },
        { title: "First Name", field: "first_name" },
        { title: "Last Name", field: "last_name" }
      ]}
      icons={{
        Add: () => <Add />,
        Check: () => <Check />,
        Clear: () => <Clear />,
        Edit: () => <Edit />,
        FirstPage: () => <FirstPage />,
        NextPage: () => <ChevronRight />,
        LastPage: () => <LastPage />,
        PreviousPage: () => <ChevronLeft />,
        ResetSearch: () => <Clear />,
        Search: () => <Search />
      }}

      // If this is an array from state(ie. this.state.data) then it works.
      data={query =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?";
          url += "per_page=" + query.pageSize;
          url += "&page=" + (query.page + 1);
          fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(result => {
              resolve({
                data: result.data,
                page: result.page - 1,
                totalCount: result.total
              });
            });
        })
      }
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: newData =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              {
                const data = this.state.data;
                data.push(newData);
                this.setState({ data }, () => resolve());
              }
              resolve();
            }, 1000);
          })
      }}
      title="Remote Data Example"
    />
  )
    }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there is a solution calling the funtion that manage all query event of Material Table

You can do it creating a a React reference to the table. And in that moment you can access to the function.
You can use this to pass values directly to the functions if you wanted.

These are the step:
1- Create a value and assign React.createRef()
let tableRef=React.createRef()

2- Assign this to the Material Table property called tableRef

tableRef={tableRef}

3- Then you can call the function onQueryChange() whitout any parameters, when you need update your table.

tableRef.current.onQueryChange()

For example:

```
`async apiDelete(IDs) {
try {
  await Service.delete(IDs);
  this.state.tableRef.current.onQueryChange();
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error Deleting" + e);
}
```

}`

You can do others things like:

  `this.state.tableRef.current.onQueryChange({filters: "value"});`

Please make a console.log(tableRef) to see all you can do.

Let me know if this help you
Regards

Comment: You must have Material Table version  1.28.0 or higher

Comment: I have tried same thing but getting this error and page crashes "TypeError: r.props.data is not a function". version is ^1.67.0

Comment: I believe you are not assigning a promise function in the props "data". 
If you still having problem I advice create a new post for your issue and share your code there? You can use codesandbox.